# Is it possible to connect PC and PS3 together using BlueTooth?

Tags: bluetooth, connection, ps3

I just bought a PS3. I don't have WIFI at home, however, my computer has BlueTooth.

I was wondering, is it possible to connect the computer with the PS3 using BlueTooth? Then I could just have my computer in my room and my PS3 can connect to it and stream music and videos from it.

Comment: No, this is not officially supported.

Comment: is there any other way to connect it then other than wifi?

Comment: You can connect the PS3 to a network using either Ethernet or WiFi. These are the only two options that support a *network*. Bluetooth on the PS3 is exclusively for peripherals (i.e. headsets, controllers).

Answer (score 0):

Use a wired connection.  Ethernet to a router should do you. You're not going to be able to browse the contents of the PS3 because it just doesn't do that.  But you can read media players from your computer.